# Can't use function return value in write context (numeric function)

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm getting the error:

> Can't use function return value in write context

when trying to use this function call:

```
<?php if ( get_price( item_1 ) = 100) { ?>
Hello
<?php } else { } ?>
```

This is the function:

```
function get_price($m) {

global $item,$i;    

  if ($m == "item_1") {
    $value =  $item[$i]["a_price"];
  }  
  else { 
    $value = $item[$i]["price"];
  }

  return $value;

}
```

The function DOES work when I do something like this though:

`<?= get_total_price( item_1 ) ?>`

Or when I use `!=` Operator like:

`<?php if ( get_price( item_1 ) != 100) { ?>`

So I have no clue what's the problem with this specific use

Comment: `=` is not a comparison it sets. So `get_price( item_1 ) = 100` is incorrect. You are trying to set the function to 100 with your current code, not possible.

Comment: How does `!=` works fine though? I noticed it check the value correctly, even though I'm not using `!==`

Comment: Because `!=` says `not equal to`, Where as `==` says `equal to`, and`=` says `set`. `===` and `!==` says the same but compare the type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in line

```
<?php if ( get_price( item_1 ) = 100) { ?>
```

It should be one more equals (=) and one more (

```
<?php if ( get_price( item_1 ) == 100)) { ?>
```

Comment: It should not be 2 `)`s at the end. This also was already addressed in the comments.